# trigonometry exercise in C

Tags: c

I need to make a program to calculate the height of a building, so I have a few variable like `s`, `alfa`, and `beta`. I need to find `u`, `phi` and the <strike>high</strike> height. So far I have that written that the program starts with two warnings for `s` and `u` that they are used uninitilized, and when I start the program it makes a good calculation for `phi`, but fails to sum `u` and then find `h`, so I get 0.000000 for `h`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double u (double s, double Alfa , double phi1) {
  double u1;
  u1 = s * (double)sin(Alfa)/ sin(phi1);
  return u1;
}

double phi (double Alfa, double Beta) {                                 
  double phi1;
  phi1 = Beta - Alfa;
  return phi1;
}

double high (double u1, double Beta, double Alfa) {
  double high1;
  double phi1;
  double s;
  phi1 = phi(Alfa, Beta);   // THIS IS THE SOLUTION, need to call the funktion before I use them in High//
  u1 = u(s, Alfa, phi1);  
  high1 = u1 * sin (Beta);

  return high1;
}

int main () {
  double s;
  double Alfa;
  double Beta;
  double high1;
  double phi1;
  double u1;

  printf("give S:");
  scanf("%lf", &s);
  printf("give  Alfa:");
  scanf("%lf", &Alfa);
  printf("Give Beta:");
  scanf("%lf", &Beta);

  high1 = high(u1, Beta, Alfa);
  phi1 = phi(Alfa, Beta);
  u1= u(s, Alfa, phi1);

  printf("The tower has a high of:   %lf Metern\n.", high1);
  printf("S is:        %lf Meter\n.", s);
  printf("     Alfa %lf Grad\n.", Alfa);
  printf("     Beta %lf Grad\n.", Beta);
  printf(" Gama %lf Grad\n.", phi1);
  return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: So what happened after you addressed those warnings?

Comment: i get all the values s, alfa and beta are already given , phi1 is calculated properly , but the programm fail to give a result for high1 its displayed 0.00000 or -0.00000 which I explain it that at some point the programm fail to give the s or more specificly u1 and it multimplies 0 to sin Beta which gives 0 ...

Comment: But, as you say in your question, it's warning you about using uninitialized variables - have you fixed that, yet?

Comment: Try everything I dont know how to fix it I already initialized the s in the main function which is suppose to be readed from there and use in the next funktion, can you give me some guidence?

Comment: The `s` in `main()` has nothing at all to do, for instance, with the `s` in `high()`. They are two completely different variables which happen to share the same name. If you want a value to go to a function, you have to pass it to that function.

Comment: I need also to make the alfa and beta and the game to be in radius (pi/180)*Alfa/Beta/Gama

Comment: i pass the s from the main funktion in u funktion, then I pass the u1 in the high where I make the failure I just dont get it spend 3 hours trying to figure it out but comes nothing..

Comment: When you pass `u1` to `high()`, you haven't initialized it yet. You need to initialize it *before* you pass it to anything, otherwise you're invoking undefined behavior and passing garbage values to your function.

Comment: So you says that I need to move phi above main u above phi and high  abouve u so that the program will first do the phi then u and then high I tryed that got some nasty error  conflicting types :( , Im so stuck I will be thankful if you can move this discussion to chat  beucase I dont have enough tokens , thats of course if you want me to help.

Comment: I dont do chat, sorry.

Comment: Ye ok I understand but do you know how to avoind this s to be uninitilized if you do can oyu please share it with me here , because you answer with a question which lead to another question and make it even more complicate to understand ...

Comment: It's hard, because your code makes little sense. You need to change the order in which you *call* your functions, not the order in which you *define* them. You'll probably need to pass an additional variable to `high()` for `s`. It's not clear what `high()` is doing, because you attempt to calculate values for `phi1` and `u1`, but then return from the function without ever attempting to use those values.

Comment: ye I finaly manage it , it was so stupid failure that I did , I need to call the u1 and phi1 funktion in heigh before I start calculating heigh1 ... thx for the assist Paul

Answer (score 3):

`u1` is uninitialized when you used it to get `high`.